# selenium + python switch_to_window

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a scraper that requires selecting a link to open a new window.  To activate the window and check that it is activated, I use :

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

driver.title

print title
```

It worked once and then never again.  I did some other check to make certain it was recognizing the windows existence and it does, yet it will not switch:

```
print len(driver.window_handles)

print driver.window_handles
```

I'm using the following website:

```
chromedriver = 'C:\Python27\drivers\chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get("https://ccrecordse.tarrantcountytx.gov/RealEstate/SearchEntry.aspx")
```

The program enters dates + lease documents, moves to the next page, clicks the document icons to open the new window, but will not switch to the new window.  I cannot figure out why.

Thanks for your help and let me know if I need to provide more information in my question!

Comment: It's not clear how you open the new window, with selenium.openWindow? do you execute selenium.selectWindow after that?

Answer (score 0):

I opened the window by using get_element_by_id.click().  But it seems I was capturing the change incorrectly, and if I print driver.title, it shows the correct handler.
Thank you!